# solve the functional equation $f(x+t)-f(x-t)=4xt$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, functional-equations

I think this question might be related with arbitrary functions, but I’m not sure. I also tried to set $t$ to different values but couldn’t get it to work.
I tried to set $t=x$ and end up with $f(2x)=f(0)+4x^2$, $f(x)=f(0)+x^2$.

Comment: You seem to have got the answer (the last formula).

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x=t$ and we get $$f(2x)-f(0)= 4x^2$$ so $f(x) =x^2+a$ where $a= f(0)$.

**Check:** If we now put this in to starting equation we get: $$ (x+t)^2+a-(x-t)^2-a = 4xt$$ which is always true. So $\boxed{f(x) =x^2+a}$ for all real $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(q) = q^2$ + const., that solves it directly. Is your question for **a** solution or for **all** solutions?

Comment: I think it’s all solutions

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary reals $a$ and $b$ plug $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $t=\frac{a-b}{2}$. Then, we obtain that
$$
f(a)-f(b)=4\cdot\frac{(a+b)(a-b)}{4}
$$
or
$$
f(a)-f(b)=a^2-b^2.
$$
Hence, $f(x)-x^2\equiv c$ for some constant $c$. It's easy to see that function $f(x)=x^2+c$ is satysfying the condition.

Comment: How did you get from f(a)-f(b)=a^2-b^2 to the last step?

Comment: It's because $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: @PeterWang One way to see it is by rewriting it as $f(a)-a^{2}=f(b)-b^{2}$. If $g(x)=h(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, then $g$ and $h$ are constant (and equal).

Answer (score 0):

As long as $f(x)$ is continuous in the Lipschitz sense, we have

$$
2\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{2t}\right) = 2f'(x) = 4x\Rightarrow f(x) = x^2+C
$$